# ListPlot3D surface with logarithmic-scale

Tags: graphics3d, logarithmic-scale

I'm tring to do a `ListPlot3D` however I don't get any answer from Mathematica. Furthermore, I'd like to introduce a log scale in the y-axis. Which function could give me the best surface from my data?

```
data = {{0.5, 10^-7, 30.32}, {0.5, 2.32 10^-7, 80.14}, {0.5, 5 10^-8, 7.52}, {0.5, 7.5 10^-8, 10.06}, {0.5, 4 10^-7, 100}, {0.5, 1 10^-8,0}, {0.75, 10^-7, 63.21}, {0.75, 2.32 10^-7, 100}, {0.75, 5 10^-8,25.39}, {0.75, 7.5 10^-8, 45.06}, {0.75, 4 10^-7, 100}, {0.75,1 10^-8, 0}, {1, 10^-7, 100}, {1, 2.32 10^-7, 100}, {1, 5 10^-8, 42.90}, {1, 7.5 10^-8, 68.88}, {1, 4 10^-7, 100}, {1, 1 10^-8, 0}, {1.5, 10^-7, 100}, {1.5, 2.32 10^-7, 100}, {1.5, 5 10^-8, 74.26}, {1.5, 7.5 10^-8, 100}, {1.5, 4 10^-7, 100}, {1.5, 1 10^-8,3.31}, {2, 10^-7, 100}, {2, 2.32 10^-7, 100}, {2, 5 10^-8, 100}, {2, 7.5 10^-8, 100}, {2, 4 10^-7, 100}, {2, 1 10^-8, 10.64}}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `ListPlot3D[data, ScalingFunctions -> {None,"Log"}]`?

Comment: Yes, but I get no answer.

Comment: Try `data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] 10^7; 
Show[ListPointPlot3D[data], ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All]]
`.  This doesn't get you the log scale but does produce a plot.

Comment: Strange that `ListPlot3D[data]` works fine in v.9 but not v.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[data, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log", None}]
```

[image]

Another possibility:

```
ListPlot3D[MapAt[Log@# &, data, {All, 2}], 
Ticks -> {Automatic, 
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][Sequence @@ MinMax[Log[data[[All, 2]]]]], 
Automatic}]
```

gives the same picture.

Comment: I don't know why, but this is not working in version 11.

Comment: Edited answer and added another possible way to plot.